# Download the contents of a Javascript variable as a named file

Tags: javascript, download

I have the contents of a file in a Javascript variable.  When the user clicks something (link, button, etc.) I want the "save as" dialog to appear with a filename specified by my code and when the user clicks "save", the contents of the Javascript variable are saved in the file.

I know how to do this using server-side code but that is not an option for this application.

I've seen several conversations on StackOverflow related to this issue and the difficulties surrounding it so I'm placing a bounty on this one to encourage creative thinking :)

Comment: Flash. Or html5 file access - All I can think of right now

Comment: Can you elaborate on using HTML5 file access? I'm comfortable with the browser restrictions this might impose.

Comment: Correction: Apparently I have to wait two days to add a bounty, so I'll do so when we get there :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file

Comment: After 3 years, i can tell you solution can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898044/is-possible-to-save-javascript-variable-as-file

Answer (score 1):

Can't really say that this is my idea (I found it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2897619/using-html5-javascript-to-generate-and-save-a-file) of all places), but have you tried [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify)? It will only work in the most modern browsers, but you don't really have a choice if you have no server-side component available.

Comment: I'll take a closer look at that but I'd prefer to avoid Flash if possible.

Comment: @mplungjan I'll wager that both posts happened almost simultaneously. I got that link through Google.

Comment: As per usual. One has to be very fast here and I tend to lose rep by posting comments instead of answers