# Multithreaded file transfer/ Download using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, multithreading

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: /myfile.exe,
                success: function(datadown) {
                    dataup.push(datadown);
                    async: false,
```

I am creating a little download manager browser based , I know javascript is single threaded and it will not support multiple process at once .
There is any way to do this in javascript (I am using Jquery)

The current method is working . It is a single threaded file download and it is slow .

I need to download the same file using multiple http connections (Just like normal download managers do )

Comment: Is this an actual snippet from your code? It has syntax errors.

Comment: "async: false" makes it "slow", and threads don't have anything to do with it. if you want parallel connections, use Range headers to grab chunks of the file, if your server supports it.

Comment: This is not actual code snippet ,Just show how I am trying to do the stuff . Using Jquery $.ajax().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to download the same file using multiple http connections

What you want to do is not possible.

- AJAX does not support resuming a file from a specific point within the file.
- Combing a file via JS is not a good idea, as it was never intended to do disk/file IO
- [You can't really download a JS variable from a browser without a plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530377/download-the-contents-of-a-javascript-variable-as-a-named-file) as [it wasn't intended to do that either (security)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax).  (if doing the action requires a plugin  then it might as well just be a plugin without JS)

Comment: There is no Alternate method ? Any cross platform method to do this ? Multithreaded file transfer/ Download using Normal web browser ?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can specify the HTTP Range header you should be fine

See
[Can I use the HTTP range header to load partial files "on purpose"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200266/can-i-use-the-http-range-header-to-load-partial-files-on-purpose)

Comment: How HTTP Range header will increase the file download speed ? I think its supports splitting the file and download .

Comment: It returns only the partial content , I need to Know how to download Multiple parts of content same time using Jquery or any other method . Through a web browser