# Is possible to save JavaScript variable as file?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to convert a string from a JavaScrip variable, into a downloadable file that users can download when clicking a button ?

Thanks for any advice.

```
<div id="txt">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<br />
<button id="test">Download text as file !</button>
```

Comment: you need some kind of server to write to file system. Node.js, PHP, Python, etc.  JavaScript alone can't do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Comment: First thank you for this question, I was searching for it, but with a different title. Please can you make title more generic, something like "download text as a file with Javascript", so it will be easier to find imho.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes it is, you could do something like this in HTML5, using the `download` attribute

```
function download_txt() {
  var textToSave = document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML;
  var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

  hiddenElement.href = 'data:attachment/text,' + encodeURI(textToSave);
  hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
  hiddenElement.download = 'myFile.txt';
  hiddenElement.click();
}

document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', download_txt);
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/wtp5a0o8/1/)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is a great solution for me.

Comment: @adeneo: Is it possible to store array of objects as text file, like var arrayToSave = [{fn:"john"},{fn:"doe"}];instead of var textToSave = 'this is a test';

Comment: @MohamedHussain - It is if you use `JSON.stringify` to stringify it first.

Comment: This works fine on Chrome, *but*: Does not work at all for Firefox on OSX (43.0.3, early 2016). Works halfway on Safari; file downloads, but with default name and it opens a blank tab.

Comment: Fiddle doesn't seem to be working at all on Firefox 45 (Ubuntu) - any way around this?

Comment: Only works in Chrome on Windows 7. Not in firefox or IE.

Comment: Not Work IN IE>8

Comment: Genius. This works fine on Firefox 78 for Mac OSX.

Comment: On firefox you must attach the <a> to the document first. you can fix this by using `document.body.appendChild(hiddenElement)` before the `hiddenElement.click()`

Answer (score 6):

You can use a data: URI like in adeneo's answer, but another way is to use an [HTML5 Blob and createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) (similarly using the download attribute to create a download link).

The benefit of using createObjectURL is that there are severe size limits to data URIs in most browsers.

Example code taken from linked article:

```
var typedArray = GetTheTypedArraySomehow();
var blob = new Blob([typedArray], {type: 'application/octet-binary'});
    // pass a useful mime type here
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
// url will be something like: blob:d3958f5c-0777-0845-9dcf-2cb28783acaf
// now you can use the url in any context that regular URLs can be used
// in, for example img.src, etc.
```

Comment: In modern browsers the length of a data URI is unlimited, some older browsers would limit it to around 65000 characters, so I wouldn't say "severe size limits" !

Comment: I could really use the rest of the example (to actually download the thing as a .json)

Answer (score 1):

To store a javascript variable, I suggest you to use [libraries of data storage just like this one](https://github.com/khaliid/happy-data.js). where you can set a variable, get it , remove it ...

```
$.setData("key","value");
$.getData("key");
$.removeData("key");
```

but to store it on a file and make downloadable you have to pass by the server unless you use a javascript trick to download a file which doesn't exist, you just declare these functions

```
 var Download = 
    {
        click : function(node) {
            var ev = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            ev.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, self, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            return node.dispatchEvent(ev);
        },
        encode : function(data) {
                return 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + btoa( data );
        },
        link : function(data, name){
            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.download = name || self.location.pathname.slice(self.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            a.href = data || self.location.href;
            return a;
        }
    };
    Download.save = function(data, name)
    {
        this.click(
            this.link(
                this.encode( data ),
                name
            )
        );
    };
```

and when you want to download a file, you do this

```
Download.save("data to be on a file","FileName.txt");
```

Finally, you need to combine the datastorage and the filedownload solution to get the result you're asking for

Comment: it is terrible, why don't use a single function? What is the point to create click, link and encode???
It is an example of bad programming.